# Report on No Results

Tags: reporting

We just started using Vision-e's business card scanner tool to scan business cards with your phone to send into Salesforce.

What the business wants to see is a dashboard of all the people who have the ability to make scans and how many scans they have made.

Where I'm struggling is that a lot of the people have yet to actually scan cards so they would not a record to report on. if they had made a scan it'd be easy.

I've been creating report types off the user, the scan object, users without scans object, users with or without scans; and none seem to be giving me a clear table of:

- User A: 1
- User B: 4
- User C: 0
- User D: 0

Has anyone come across this use case before and how did you solve?

Comment: What you're asking about is very similar to adoption reports/dashboards for new implementations. Take a look at the standard Salesforce Reports on the subject.

Comment: Solid advice, it looks like you need a field to flag on user to count scans like they do with last login.